# spring MVC, data-biding of a List containing abstracts

Tags: forms, spring, generics, spring-mvc, data-binding

I try to bind a generic list containing B,C objects which are A objects.

```
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "type", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING)
public abstract class A<T> {

    @Column(name = "type", nullable = false, updatable = false, insertable = false)
    private String type;

    @Column(name = "value")
    private String value;

    // used to populate the value in the inner class
    public abstract void setCustomValue(T value);
}

@DiscriminatorValue("b")
public class B extends A<Integer>{
    public void setCustomValue(Integer value);
}

@DiscriminatorValue("c")
public class C extends A<Boolean>{
    public void setCustomValue(Boolean value);
}
```

This is the velocity template and the binding form:

public class AForm {

```
    private List<A<?>> a;

    public AForm() {
            a = new ArrayList<A<?>>();
    }

    public AForm(List<A<?>> a) {
            super();
            this.a = a;
    }
```

}

```
<form action="#springUrl("....")" method="post">
...
#foreach($a in $aList.a)
        #set( $index = $velocityCount - 1 )
        <tr>
            <td>
            #springFormInput("aList.a[$index].type" "") 
            </td>
            <td>
            #springFormInput("aList.a[$index].customValue" "") 
            </td>
        </tr>   
#end
...
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

But when I save the form, spring try to instantiate an object A instead of the object (B or C) depending of the type given for each object in the form.
I guess I have to make a custom binding but I have no idea how to do it.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you resolve this issue? I have the same question

Comment: I bypassed the issue by changing the form to handle generics outside the spring binding. Definitely not the best way to do it, but it's hard to find documentation about Spring complex binding.